# C# Entity Framework with LIKE

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an application with the following code:

```
string passedValue = "5";
results = db.procedure1
            .Where(c => c.User.Contains(passedValue))
            .OrderBy(o => o.User).ToList();
```

The data in the `Users` column looks like this:

```
 05621
 18763
 58763
 98599
```

When I run the code, the resulting list contains 05621, 58763, and 98599

Instead of a `Contains`, I would like to implement a `Like`. In other words, I want to retrieve each data record where `User is LIKE "5%"`.

The resulting list should be:

```
 58763
```

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`?

Comment: For the record, `Contains` is the same as `User LIKE "%5%"`, `StartsWith` will be the same as `User LIKE "5%"` and `EndsWith` the same as `User LIKE "%5"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `.Where()` clause that you have with something like below:

```
string passedValue = "5";
results = db.procedure1
            .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.User, $"%{passedValue}%"))
            .OrderBy(o => o.User).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For `LIKE "5%"` we have `StartsWith` so you can do like this

```
string passedValue = "5";
results = db.procedure1
            .Where(c => c.User.StartsWith(passedValue))
            .OrderBy(o => o.User).ToList();
```

For `LIKE "%5"` we have `EndsWith` and `LIKE "%5%" -` Contains`